# Grails not matching url pattern with optional parameter

Tags: grails

On Grails 2.3.7, assume the following url mappings..

```
"/foo/$number?"     (controller:'test', action:'actionOne')  
"/foo/$number?/bar" (controller:'test', action:'actionTwo')
```

..and controller:

```
class TestController {
   def actionOne(){ render "Action_ONE: ${params.number}"  }
   def actionTwo(){ render "Action_TWO: ${params.number}" }
}
```

**All good...**

```
/foo/1      //prints 'Action_ONE: 1'
/foo/2/bar  //prints 'Action_TWO: 2'
/foo//bar   //prints 'Action_TWO: null'
/foo//      //prints 'Action_ONE: null'
```

**...but**

```
/foo   //prints 'Action_TWO: null'
/foo/  //prints 'Action_TWO: null'
```

If `number` is optional in `/foo/$number?`, why does `/foo` and `/foo/` map to `actionTwo()`?

Comment: This is replicable in 2.4.2. Looks like a bug to me, you can raise a JIRA issue here https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS.

Comment: Are optional components supposed to work at all if they're not at the end of the URI?

Comment: @IanRoberts While not explicitly stated, according to the docs, yes, but that's not the issue, `/foo/` should never map to `action2()`. btw, does order in which URL patterns listed in `URLMappings.groovy` matter in terms of precedence? I don't believe so, just curious.

Comment: No, the ordering is not relevant.  The most specific mapping wins, but the rules for "most specific" are not officially documented.  Last time I looked at the code (which was in 2.2.x) the winning mapping would be the one with the first of (a) fewer `**` double wildcards, (b) fewer single-wildcards, (c) more static path segments, (d) the first wildcard further to the left or (e) more entries in its `constraints {}` block.

Comment: The relevant code is the [`compareTo` method of `RegexUrlMapping`](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-web-url-mappings/src/main/groovy/org/grails/web/mapping/RegexUrlMapping.java#L720), and it looks like it's still the same rules now.

Comment: @IanRoberts I understand, but the match in this case is not intuitive; don't you agree? Why would `/foo/` match a pattern with a literal `/bar` component when `/foo/$optional` is already a pattern? makes no sense.

Comment: Have you tried adding the mappings logging to your Log4j configuration to see how the matching is being done? Maybe if you paste that log in the question you can help us figure out what's happening. The line you have to add is: all 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping'

Answer (score 0):

in below two line

```
"/foo/$number?"     (controller:'test', action:'actionOne')  
"/foo/$number?/bar" (controller:'test', action:'actionTwo')
```

you have defined number as optional in url , as you have used "?" . Change "$number?" to "$number" in

```
 "/foo/$number?/bar" (controller:'test', action:'actionTwo')
```

second line and it should work fine .

here are details on url mapping https://grails.org/version/URL+mapping/8